# Time stamp issue while adding event in facebook using graph API

Tags: facebook

What is the valid format for start_time and end_time while adding an event using graph api ...
i tried adding an event using unix time stamp .. however its not showing the same date when the event is published ..

when i give start_time as 1293802200 which is 31st Dec 2010 07:00 pm .. it shows as 31st Dec 5:30am on facebook ..

what is it that am doing wrong .. do i need to consider time zone issues as well ??

Regards
Abhishek Jain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/ it seems that you need to specify date in the Pacific time zone (PST).

Now, the timestamp value you provided is 31st Dec 2010 19:00 in India indeed which corresponds to same day, 5:30 in Pacific time.

In conclusion, convert your local time to Pacific time (PST) prior to uploading it to Facebook.