# Daylight Savings Time and Event API

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I know that the API returns times that are converted ([through a very convoluted process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552204/time-stamp-issue-while-adding-event-in-facebook-using-graph-api)) to ISO-8601. My question is, is the conversion made while taking into account the local daylight savings (or not) of a given location? The [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) says nothing about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just worked on this on Friday.

I can confirm that if you have the Events Timezone migration enabled, the ISO-8601 dates that are returned are corrected for the presence/absence of Daylight Savings at the events start / end time.